# Выведены ли коэффициенты формул Флеша-Кинкейда для русского языка?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, компьютеры

Американцы обожают на всё навешивать ярлык с оценкой, причём одной цифрой.
Существует такой себе тест читаемости текста Флеша-Кинкейда, который предназначен для определения трудности восприятия при чтении текста на современном академическом английском языке. Основой его являются две формулы:

1) лёгкость читаемости = 206,835 - 1,015х(всего слов/всего предложений)- 84,6х(всего слогов/всего слов);
2) возраст (образованность) читающего = 0,39х(всего слов/всего предложений) + 11,8х(всего слогов/всего слов)  - 15.59

Числовые коэффициенты, по мысли разработчиков, учитывают структуру английского языка.

Вопрос: есть ли обоснование коэффициентов этих формул для русского языка? Google ничего путного не даёт... Возможно, у нас это называется как-то по-другому?

Comment: Запишите формулы как-то более более по-человечески. 
Какой, например, смысл вычитать из непонятной константы два частных непонятного содержания?

Comment: Это похоже на два высказывания:

1) v = -1,015x + -84,6y + 206,835,

2) w = 0,39x + 11,8y + -15,59.

Скорей всего, значения коэффициентов определены методом наименьших квадратов.

Чтобы оценить полезность вышеуказанных высказываний, найдите и сравните  значения v и w для текстов:

а) "Ночь, улица, фонарь, аптека, бессмысленный и тусклый свет. Живи ещё хоть четверть века - всё будет так. Исхода нет.",

б) "Ночь. Улица. Фонарь. Аптека. Бессмысленный и тусклый свет. Живи ещё хоть четверть века - всё будет так. Исхода нет.".

Comment: @behemothus: Более по-человечески здесь http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests , но на английском.  
Смысл? Ну, захотел мр.Флеш как-то выставлять оценку легкости чтения текста (1) или прикинуть, на каком году обучения человек способен понять предложенный текст (2). Причём решил он, что это можно слелать, основываясь на параметрах текста (всего слов/всего предложений) и (всего слогов/всего слов).  
А некоторые ведомства в США возьми, да и сделай это отраслевым стандартом...

Comment: @Галактион: Очень может быть, но потеть над МНК мне как-то не с руки. В США годы потели, кучу текстов перелопатили, пока те коэффициенты вывели...  
У нас вон тоже человек потеет: https://www.mashape.com/ivbeg/measure-readability-of-russian-texts#!readme  
Но, может, кто-то уже это сделал?

Answer (score 1):

> Смысл? Ну, захотел мр.Флеш как-то выставлять оценку легкости чтения текста (1) или прикинуть, на каком году обучения человек способен понять предложенный текст (2). Причём решил он, что это можно слелать, основываясь на параметрах текста (всего слов/всего предложений) и (всего слогов/всего слов).

Вот я и спрашиваю о смысле этой манипуляции. Взять, поделить, вычесть... А почему не сложить и умножить? Бесполезно говорить о формуле, неизвестно что подставляющий...
Далее, если это эмпирические коэффициенты, то сразу - ффтопку. Не бывает эмпирики, определяемой до пятого знака. Максимум - два. Если же это аппроксимация (как полагает Галактион), то что именно аппроксимировалось?!

(+)
Посмотрел, благо тырнет позволил.
Мнения не изменил, скорее наоборот.
Она, эта формула, оказывается еще и военного происхождения. История на тему "в военное время наш новый синус доходил до трех". 
Короче, поскольку непонятно, что именно эта формула должна характеризовать, то и говорить о её перенесении "на русскую почву" тем более бесполезно.

Comment: Возможно, Вы будете смеяться, но я с Вами солидарен. Явно, что средняя длина предложения в словах и слова в слогах недостаточна для определения, насколько этот текст будет легко читаться. Напрашиваются хотя бы частотные характеристики слов.  
Вот такая она, непознанная англосаксонская душа: основываясь на среднепотолочных данных, выводить формулы с точностью до 5-го знака. Но это ж для компа...   
Но чисто бюрократически части русского народа тоже числовой оценки хочется - хотя бы приблизительно узнать, начиная с какого класса поймут конкретный текст. И меня интересует прогресс в этом плане.

Answer (score 1):

Официальной формулы читаемости нет, но вот [тут](http://ru.readability.io/) ее разрабатывают.
Если будете пользоваться, поделитесь потом своим опытом, хорошо?

Answer (score 0):

А разве по этой ссылке не имеется в виду русский язык? Текст-то на русском...

http://office.microsoft.com/ru-ru/word-help/HP010148506.aspx

Когда в Outlook и Word заканчивается проверка правописания и грамматики, можно вывести на экран сведения об уровне удобочитаемости документа, включая показатели удобочитаемости по следующим тестам:
•   Удобочитаемость по Флешу
•   Школьный уровень по Флешу-Кинкейду
Формула расчета показателя удобочитаемости по Флешу:
206.835 – (1.015 x ASL) – (84.6 x ASW)
где
ASL = средняя длина предложения (число слов, деленное на число предложений)
ASW = среднее число слогов в слове (число слогов, деленное на число слов)
Школьный тест по Флешу-Кинкейду

А вот по этой разве речь не обо всех европейских языках? http://leav.ru/yp/8_14.htm

Comment: Спасибо, это я видел. Речь идёт не обо всех европейских языках - для русского это не выводится. Может, у меня Ворд устарел? Попробую поискать версию посвежее...

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, откуда берутся коэффициенты  (равно как и ваше предубеждение против "американцев") и как именно приводятся цифры (в какой системе записи). Первая цифра 206,835 и поскольку система американская, то предположим, что это, скорее всего, просто разрядный разделитель...

Пример соотнесения количества слов и количества слогов основан на базовом принципе "простого английского": односложные слова относятся к исконной лексике и чаще всего воспринимаются как самые понятные.

Поскольку для русского языка преобладание односложных слов нехарактерно как минимум в цензурном регистре, то принцип формулы должен быть иным.